# using while loop to count how many doublings happen between two numbers

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, conditional-statements

My task is to write a function that uses a while loop to count how many days(how many doublings) it takes for the population to go from a given initial size to a value greater than or equal to a given final size.

In addition, The answer should be zero if the final populations is less than or equal to the initial population.

My approach:

```
def num_doublings(initial_population, final_population):
    days = 0
    if final_population <= initial_population:
        return 0
    else:
        while initial_population < final_population:
            initial_population * 2
            days = days + 1
        return days
```

Testing:

```
ans = num_doublings(1, 8)
print(ans)
```

When i press enter, it tells me "executing command. please wait for results."
and i don't think it'll ever return something so i just discontinue the code from running.

So what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `initial_population *= 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `initial_population * 2`, which does **not** modify the in-place variable. Instead try:

```
initial_population *= 2
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
initial_population = initial_population*2
```

Final Code:

```
def num_doublings(initial_population, final_population):
    days = 0
    if final_population <= initial_population:
        return 0
    else:
        while initial_population < final_population:
            initial_population *= 2 #Right here
            days += 1 #Also changed this to be more concise
        return days
```

**Why this is an issue:**

You are testing for `if x < y`, and if `x` is indeed less than `y`, and you do not modify either `x` or `y`, your while loop will run indefinitely.